# Looping mat-icon based on number value in template

Tags: angular

I have  mat-table where I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to output the `<mat-icon>star</mat-icon>` times the number from `row.rating`. For example if the rating is a 4, I want the mat icon star to appear 4 times to represent 4 stars. The stars go up to 5. The only way I can think of doing it is using *ngIf for `<span id="ratingValue"><mat-icon>star</mat-icon></span` with 5 different scenarios each with a different number of stars to represent the `row.rating` value, but I don't think that is very efficient. I was hoping to get some ideas. I appreciate any help!

```
    <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">

      <ng-container class="tableStyle" matColumnDef="rating">
        <th id="dateReceivedHeader" class="tableStyle" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Rating
        <td [ngStyle]="{'width': '20%'}" class="tableStyle" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <span id="ratingValue">
            {{row.rating}}<mat-icon>star</mat-icon></span></td>
      </ng-container>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a reusable rating component as I show in this example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-start-raiting?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstart-raiting%2Fstart-raiting.component.ts)

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I thought it was bad to use functions in component like that? Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp

Comment: @user6680 put changedetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush, and everithing should be fine